# Installing `nginx-dav-ext-module` to Nginx but keeps getting not compatible error

Tags: nginx, module, centos7

I was trying to install this [module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-dav-ext-module) to a server to make utilities of full WebDAV functionalities.

I had built and installed `Nginx-1.20.0` from source previously using arguments

```
--prefix=/var/www/html --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --with-pcre --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --modules-path=/etc/nginx/modules --with-http_v2_module --with-stream=dynamic --with-http_addition_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_dav_module
```

and it worked just fine.

### Method

I've cloned the module file by

```sh
git clone https://github.com/arut/nginx-dav-ext-module
```

Built the modules by the following command, using **exactly the same file** used to build and install Nginx in the beginning.

```sh
./configure --with-compat --with-http_dav_module --add-dynamic-module=../nginx-dav-ext-module/
```

Copied the file to the `Modules` folder

```sh
cp objs/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so /etc/nginx/modules/
```

And loaded the module by add this directive at the beginning (outside of http context) of `nginx.conf`

```
load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;
```

### Result

As I run the check `nginx -t`, I got

```
nginx: [emerg] module "/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:4
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I've done some search and found that it can be related to `--with-compat`. However it doesn't solve my problem.

What could possibly go awry?

Comment: I have an article in my boormarks on this subject, but it is written in Russian. Nevertheless  before anyone else answered this I think it is better than nothing, you can try to use some automatic translation service, so [give it a try](https://habr.com/ru/company/nixys/blog/473578/).